# Drupal 7 Date module All day otpion

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I am using Drupal 7 Date module. I have enabled it and created a date field with Date, Time and All day option in the content type. I created a node of that content type, I set the date to 04/25/2015, checked All day option and saved the node. After saving the node I can see my date field value being saved as 04/24/2015 00:00:00 in the database. But I am expecting it to be saved as 04/24/2015 23:59:59.
Can any one please help me how to achieve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Good morning. You should modify the submitted info after the submision of the form. Have a look at [hook_node_presave()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7), a hook which lets you alter the node before it is inserted into database.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Bustikiller for your response. I tried that option and the node is saving properly but when I tried to edit the node the date field is showing as 04/24/2015 23:59:59 but "All Day" checkbox is unchecked. Not sure how to solve this issue.

Comment: You are tricking the Drupal usual management of info. You have to perform the change before saving the info (as you have already done), and you need to change the info when it is being shown too. You can use hook_node_load().